# Log in using AD credentials in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I am using following code to validate AD users

```
string strLDAP = "LDAP://dc=ADServerIP/cn=Users,DC=Domain;
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(strLDAP, usr, pwd);
object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
return true;
```

I am getting the following exception when executing

```
object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
```

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80005000): Unknown error (0x80005000)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_NativeObject()

The same code is working for another AD server. What may be the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063642/how-to-know-if-my-directoryentry-is-really-connected-to-my-ldap-directory  It might be a simple connection issue. The network is invoved at NativeObject, not at New()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you working on .NET 3.5 or newer? If so, you can use the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace and easily verify your credentials:

```
// create a "principal context" - e.g. your domain (could be machine, too)
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN", usr, pwd))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```

It's simple, it's reliable, it's 100% C# managed code on your end - what more can you ask for? :-)

Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Comment: where to specify AD server name And My Domain?

Comment: @Roshe: you need to provide the domain name as second parameter to the constructor of `PrincipalContext` - no AD server name needed.

Comment: Thanks Marc_s, what about the comment on guest user by chrish in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-sharp-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory
do I need to configure anything for guest user if it is enabled?